# Refactoring jQuery to use $(this) and add/remove classes from another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, switch-statement, this

so I have this idea I'm working on over on Codepen. I've got it working as it is but before I go and add more clickable areas I've realized a massive need to refactor and DRY things up. So far it works but it's ugly as hell and would involve a massive amount of repeated code.

So I'm trying to replace the many `$(.class).click(function() { ... });` functions with a switch statement that uses $(this) to populate a single .click function instead. But I'm lost.

You can see everything here and edit it also: http://codepen.io/lukewatts/pen/ubtmI

I feel like I'm close but I've hit a wall. The top commented out part is the DRY attempt while what is uncommented for now is the working version. Click the min, off, max words or the LEDs to see it work.

Thank you very much in advance for any advise on this. PHP is my main language to be honest.

P.S. I had `leds.click(function() { ... })` and I replaced it with `leds.on(function() { ... })` but still nothing.

Comment: Haven't seen that `case switch` approach before...interesting.

Comment: I think that [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask the question. I am taking a look, though, and I don't think your `switch` idea is necessarely better.

Comment: You should start with JSLInt or JShint.

Comment: I think that peculiar `case switch` is actually the problem... does it work that way? :-/

Comment: See that's my php logic taking over. Switch statements are pretty regular in PHP but I don't see them much in Javascript. I'll admit using the $(...) in the case felt all kinds of wrong. But I've checked MDN for the syntax and the switch should be fine.

Comment: I think both your script and your markup here are totally wacky. You have the data represented on half the DOM elements and then separately in the script; pick an approach and go with it for consistency. You'll get better reuse if similar elements work similarly.

Comment: This question is off topic as it belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Sorry, I'd never heard  of Code Review until now. I'll check there also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you are trying to do, but that not how the jQuery object works. In order to check for the object to match a selector, you will have to use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

As such, you will not be able to use a `switch`, but you will have to use a serie of chained `if`s to achieve the goal the way you are trying, such as

```
if ( $this.is('.led[data-level="one"]') )
   var led = $('p.min a');
   var level = "one";
```

I have updated your CodePen example to work in this way: <kbd>[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FhHCl)</kbd>

As I mentioned in my comment to the question, though, I am not making any code review here, just fixing what didn't work for you. I am not sure this is actually a better approach than your *messy* original one, to be entirely honest.

Comment: Thanks. This does work. There;s actually going to be 13 leds / levels around the dial so I guess I'm trading 13 ifs for 13 `.click(function() { ... })` Not ideal by any means. But a switch or if to set the variables is a bit more reusable than just doing .click methods 13 times...I'm hoping. Thanks again.

Comment: Refactoring the code is always an interesting challenge. Certainly look for what's cleaner, but, in the end, aim for what's **more maintainable**. Most of the times these two overlap, but other times we simply didn't ask the correct question. Good job with the dial, it looks great.

Answer (score 1):

The refactored version looks good for me. If you don't like to use addClass and removeClass you may directly change the *class* property of the element:

```
indicator.attr("class", "one on");
```

Comment: Thanks. I just think more than one or two remove/addClass looks messy.  Once I repeat something more than once I'll always try looking for a simpler alternative. I'll try this out.

Comment: `Indicator.attr("class", "indicator off");` Worked perfectly. Thanks. Much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your switch statement doesn't work is because every time you create a jQuery object, it gets an Id, so when the switch tries to compare `$this` to a selector like `$(p.min a)`, they won't be equal. However, if you used multiple if statements with `$.is`, you could compare:

```
$this = $(this)
if($this.is('p.min a')) {
   // do work
} else if($this.is('p.max a')) {
   // do work
}
```

I wouldn't, however, recommend this approach. For more complex pages, I'd recommend a binding framework like Knockout.js. For something small, you're adding a lot of complexity. For clarity: If this becomes part of a larger control set or system, a binding framework would be useful. For the control as-is, both a binding framework and the OP's current approach are overkill.

Comment: Ah, okay. Would this still be wrong. `switch($this) case .is('p.min a'):` etc. Is it because I can't use the jQuery methods in a case? It's just I've always used switch (in PHP admittedly) when lots of ifelses are needed.

Comment: I'd like to take back my upvote now that you suggested a binding framework for something this simple.

Comment: @Mathletics didn't I say "for more complex pages"? I wasn't recommending a binding framework for this simple control.

Comment: @LukeWatts Right, you cant use jQuery methods in a switch like that.

Comment: Also, there's gonna be twelve more leds going around the dial...hence the need to think everything over now. So as it stands I'm trading 13 .click(...) instances for 13 if statements. A framework probably is necessary but this was just an idea for codepen really. :/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at event delegation, I find it very helpful to keeping things DRY. Clicks will bubble up the DOM tree to higher elements, and you can register your handler on an ancestral element. This is actually ideal, as you only bind a single handler to a single element, instead of binding to multiple elements and thus you realize a performance benefit in addition to cleaner code.

First thing, wrap all your `.led` elements in a `<div id="leds">`:

```
 <div id="leds">
     <a href="#" class="led" data-level="one"></a>
     <a href="#" class="led" data-level="thirteen"></a>
 </div>
```

Now create your handler:

```
   $('#leds').bind('click', function(e){
    var target = e.target;
    var $target = $(target);

       //do interesting stuff
       if (target.nodeName === 'A') {
            var level = $target.data('level');
            if(level = 'one'){
                //do more interesting stuff
            }
        }       
     }
    });
```